# How to get status of file exist or not | linux |

Tags: linux

I have a scenario where i want the status of command got execute

i am checking file in particular path exist or not

But i got stuck at one point where both the cases are returning success = 0

```
fail = 1 
success = 0

find /demo/ -type f -name "student.txt"
```

When above command is executed if file exist then it gives the status as  `echo $? => 0`

even if files does not exist then also it gives `echo $? => 0` where it should give `status as 1`

Comment: `[ -f "/demo/student.txt" ]` ? `where it should give` no it shouldn't - `find` finds files matching a pattern, but it doesn't exit with error when there are no files that _match_ the pattern you requested. If no files match a pattern, it's still a success. Are you trying to find `student.txt` file in all subdirectories recursively under `/demo/` directory?

Comment: @KamilCuk  No at only the same path which i provided not on entire directory … if file does not present at provided path then display status 0 or 1

Comment: @KamilCuk  -> [ -f "/demo/student.txt" ]    this is working for me thanks it returns status 1 if file not found and return success 0 if file found

Answer (score 0):

Just use `test` command to test for existence of a file:

```
[ -f "/demo/student.txt" ]
```